# I am following the Firebase Assistant , But I am getting Errors with the given query to read data

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read data from the collection "dataToSave" , where field "Email" is equals to "test11@test11.com" , I am following the firebase assistant documentation but still getting an error.

```
    db.collection("dataToSave")
            .where("Email", "==", "test11@test11.com")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            //       Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    } else {
                        //    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

I am expecting to see an output of all relevant data where email is equal to "test11@test11.com"

[Image of where error is occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoKAw.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text. Let the image stay as that shows the red line with the error. Also, if you hover over the red underline, does it show you any pop-up?

Comment: Thank you, It is saying the following --- 'where(com.google.firebase.firestore.Filter)' has private access in 'com.google.firebase.firestore.Query'

Comment: Did Ahmed's answer help?

Comment: Yes, its working now!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
db.collection("dataToSave").whereEqualTo("Email", "test11@test11.com")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.